# Trying to get List of Event Logs into a dataGridView | getting error on ReadEventLog() method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-log

I need to get this list of event logs `public static List<EventLogEntry> _LogEntries { get; private set; }` into `dataGridView` in Windows Forms.

> Current Issue: Everytime I call the method `ReadEventLog()` it breaks with the exception **An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.dll** at the line `EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(EvlLocation);`

---

First I open the file

```
    // Open the log file
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        string evlLocation = "";
        // Show file open dialog
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Create a dataset for binding the data to the grid.
            ds = new DataSet("EventLog Entries");
            ds.Tables.Add("Events");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("ComputerName");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("EventId");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("EventType");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("SourceName");
            ds.Tables["Events"].Columns.Add("Message");
            // Start the processing as a background process
            evlLocation = openFile.FileName;
            parser.setLogLocation(openFile.FileName);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(openFile.FileName);
        }
    }
```

// Then the below method is called.

```
    // Bind the dataset to the grid.
    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        parser.ReadEventLog();
        bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Events");
        Foo foo1 = new Foo("TEST PC");
        ComputerName.Add(foo1);

        bs.DataSource = parser._LogEntries;
        //Bind fooList to the dataGridView
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

        this.Invoke(pbHandler, new object[] { 100, 100 });
    }
```

---

Then when `ReadEventLog()` is called it breaks at the line `EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(EvlLocation);`
`ReadEventLog()` method below

```
    public static void ReadEventLog()
    {
        // Line in question below
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(EvlLocation);
        EventLogEntryCollection eventLogEntries = eventLog.Entries;
        int eventLogEntryCount = eventLogEntries.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogEntries.Count; i++)
        {
            EventLogEntry entry = eventLog.Entries[i];
            //Do Some processing on the entry
        }
        _LogEntries = eventLogEntries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().ToList();
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In the MSDN documentation for [EventLog Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9hdxtte(v=vs.110).aspx) - `public EventLog(string logName)` - we read under **Exceptions**:

> [ArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) | The log name is invalid.

In `ReadEventLog()` you construct `EventLog` using a parameter named `EvlLocation`. But nowhere in the code you've shown do you initialize that property. Instead, in `OpenFile()` you initialize a local variable:

```
string evlLocation = "";
// ...
evlLocation = openFile.FileName;
```

1. Ensure you initialize`EvlLocation`.
2. If the error persists, verify the string passed from `openFile.FileName` is valid - because the constructor doesn't seem to agree.